# getContentPane not working - "symbol not found" error

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a project (the same one as my last question) and I'm deciding to implement `JButtons` to "craft" weapons and gear, but in the example on how to implement a `JButton`, it used initialization, `buttonName.setText()` (I'm ignoring this because in my initialization, I already set the text) and the `getContentPane().add(buttonName);`. I tried using the line to set up the `JButton` but to no avail. I got this error: `Adventurine.java:272: error: cannot find symbol.`
Any ideas as to why this is, or am I just being an idiot and I'm missing something?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here's the code I'm using in 3 different styles:

**Style 1:**

```
private JButton craftClub = new JButton("Craft A Club");
getContentPane().add(craftClub);
```

**Style 2:**

```
private JButton craftClub = new JButton("Craft A Club");
frame.getContentPane().add(craftClub);
```

**Style 3:**

```
private JButton craftClub = new JButton("Craft A Club");
frame.getContentpane();
frame.add(craftClub);
```

- For style 1, I get `cannot find symbol errors` on `getContentPane` and `craftClub`.
- For style 2, I get `<identifier> expected` on the `getContentPane` before the `(` and a `;` expected on the `.` in `.add(craftClub);`.
- For style 3, I get `<identifier> expected`

Comment: You're going to find that SO is more helpful when you include the actual code for your issue, and the actual error stacktrace.

Comment: I have the code, but I'm missing the error stacktrace, I don't know where to find it on macs

Comment: That's a compiler error, not an exception.

Comment: never said it was an exception, I just want to know if I'm screwing up

Comment: Are you using java.awt.Frame or javax.swing.JFrame

Comment: Are you actually adding you buttons to a frame or just some other panel/container?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm using javax.swing.JFrame and java.awt.* as my imports and yes, I'm adding them to the frame, would it be better to add them during frame setup, or can I just add them anywhere?

Comment: A runnable example which demonstrates your problem would be more helpful

Answer (score 2):

This...

```
private JButton craftClub = new JButton("Craft A Club");
getContentPane().add(craftClub);
```

looks suspicious. It looks like you're trying to add your button outside of a method or executional context. Either that or you're misdefining your variables, although, I'd expect to see a different error.

Instead, you should be adding your button only from within an executional context, like a method or constructor, for example...

```
public class Awesomeness {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton craftClub = new JButton("Craft A Club");

    public Awesomeness() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame = ...;
                //...
                frame.add(craftButton);
                // frame.getContentPane().add(craftButton);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could use more of the code, but some clues in what you have written give me an idea.  I think you're putting this line in the wrong place:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(craftClub);
```

I think you probably have code like:

```
class Demo {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame( "MyFrame" );
    private JButton craftClub = new JButton("Craft A Club");
    frame.getContentPane().add(craftClub); // This is bad

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        // more stuff here
    }
}
```

And that's the problem.  You need to know the difference between declaration and initialization.

Change your code to something like this:

```
class Demo {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton craftClub;

    Demo() {
        frame = new JFrame( "MyFrame" );
        craftClub = new JButton("Craft A Club");
        frame.getContentPane().add(craftClub);  // this code is called when you new Demo() in the main
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        // more stuff here
    }
}
```

If this isn't enough to get you where you want to be... you need to post more of your code so I can answer more in your context.

Comment: So you're saying that it NEEDS to be added within the JFrame setup? because that isn't where I have it right now?

Comment: I'm saying you can't execute code (besides "new" statements that you shouldn't do there anyway) in the same area you declare members of your class.  I moved that "frame.getContentPane().add" call to a place where it's legal to be.   But I'm only guessing that you were doing that wrong, since you only chose to show us like 2 lines of code.

Comment: I had tried outside the JFrame setup, thats probably why, sorry I couldn't get enough context